# How to add the weight as an estimators for the ensemble using brew module in python?

Tags: python, classification

I'm trying to apply ensembleclassifier in my python program. I'm using [brew](https://github.com/viisar/brew) package as module. And I tried some codes from brew documentation. Like the following piece of codes that I use to initialize ensemble with combiner "mean".

```
# Initializing Classifiers
clf1 = MLPClassifier(alpha=0.0001, epsilon=1e-09, max_iter=15000,hidden_layer_sizes=(500,))
clf2 = SVC(kernel='rbf', gamma=3, C=1, max_iter=15000, probability=True)
clf3 = SVC(kernel='linear', C=1, max_iter=15000, probability=True)

# Creating Ensemble
ensemble = Ensemble([clf1, clf2, clf3])
eclf = EnsembleClassifier(ensemble=ensemble, combiner=Combiner('mean'))
```

I've tried to add weight in the initialization, like :

```
eclf = EnsembleClassifier(ensemble=ensemble, combiner=Combiner('mean'), weights=[2,3,1])
```

but it didnt work.
however when weight is removed, the program can be run...
Can we add the weight as an estimators for the ensemble in brew? If you can, what code that used to implement it?